# Adding items from xml String array into recycler view within a fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Im having some trouble trying to add an array of cities into each item location inside my fragment list. I have created the dummy list template for my fragment but can't find anything online about how to store the values on my array in an Strings.xml file into the values inside the recycler view. I want to replace the dummy items (e.g. 1: item 1, 2: item 2 etc.) with the names of cities in my array. please help!!!

xml file:

```
<resources>

    <string-array name="Cities">
        <item>Vancouver</item>
        <item>Kamloops</item>
        <item>Edmonton</item>
        <item>Calgary</item>
        <item>Winnipeg</item>
        <item>Toronto</item>
        <item>Montreal</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Fragment file:

```
package com.example.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.fragments.dummy.DummyContent;
import com.example.fragments.dummy.DummyContent.DummyItem;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * A fragment representing a list of Items.
 * <p/>
 * Activities containing this fragment MUST implement the {@link OnListFragmentInteractionListener}
 * interface.
 */
public class citiesFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Customize parameter argument names
    private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
    // TODO: Customize parameters
    private int mColumnCount = 1;
    private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public citiesFragment() {
    }

    // TODO: Customize parameter initialization
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static citiesFragment newInstance(int columnCount) {
        citiesFragment fragment = new citiesFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cities_list, container, false);

        // Set the adapter
        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
            }
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new MycitiesRecyclerViewAdapter(DummyContent.ITEMS, mListener));
        }
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onListFragmentInteraction(DummyItem item);
    }
}
```

layout:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView 
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:id="@+id/list" 
    android:name="com.example.fragments.citiesFragment" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" 
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager" 
    tools:context=".citiesFragment" 
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_cities" />
```

Adapter file:

```
/**
 * {@link RecyclerView.Adapter} that can display a {@link DummyItem} and makes a call to the
 * specified {@link OnListFragmentInteractionListener}.
 * TODO: Replace the implementation with code for your data type.
 */
public class MycitiesRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MycitiesRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<DummyItem> mValues;
    private final OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public MycitiesRecyclerViewAdapter(List<DummyItem> items, OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
        mValues = items;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_cities, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.mIdView.setText(mValues.get(position).id);
        holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).content);

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (null != mListener) {
                    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                    mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final TextView mIdView;
        public final TextView mContentView;
        public DummyItem mItem;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_number);
            mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
        }
    }
}
```

dummy content file:

```
    /**
```

* Helper class for providing sample content for user interfaces created by
 * Android template wizards.
 *

* TODO: Replace all uses of this class before publishing your app.
 */
public class DummyContent {

```
/**
 * An array of sample (dummy) items.
 */
public static final List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<DummyItem>();

/**
 * A map of sample (dummy) items, by ID.
 */
public static final Map<String, DummyItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, DummyItem>();

private static final int COUNT = 25;

static {
    // Add some sample items.
    for (int i = 1; i <= COUNT; i++) {
        addItem(createDummyItem(i));
    }
}

private static void addItem(DummyItem item) {
    ITEMS.add(item);
    ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
}

private static DummyItem createDummyItem(int position) {
    return new DummyItem(String.valueOf(position), "Item " + position, makeDetails(position));
}

private static String makeDetails(int position) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("Details about Item: ").append(position);
    for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
        builder.append("\nMore details information here.");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

/**
 * A dummy item representing a piece of content.
 */
public static class DummyItem {
    public final String id;
    public final String content;
    public final String details;

    public DummyItem(String id, String content, String details) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
        this.details = details;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have to create `DummyItem` from resource array `Cities`

Comment: what do you mean? I'm new to mobile dev

Comment: in your "fragment_cities_list.xml" file, what is the parent view ? can you share your xml file.

Comment: yeah one second

Comment: sorry I have to post it in the comments, it won't let me edit my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create `DummyItem` from resource array `Cities` and pass it to your `adapter`. Check below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cities_list, container, false);

    // Set the adapter
    if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
        Context context = view.getContext();

        //Get cities array from resource
        String[] cities = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Cities);
        List<DummyItem> mValues = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            mValues.add(new DummyItem(String.valueOf(i + 1), cities[i], ""));
        }

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
        if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        } else {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
        }

        //Pass the mValues to adapter
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MycitiesRecyclerViewAdapter(mValues, mListener));
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: So, this would go into the adapter file?

Comment: yeah im trying to figure it out, its not working because there was another file I didn't know about called dummy content and it is messing it up

Comment: The file is up now

Comment: Pass empty to your DummyItem like `new DummyItem(String.valueOf(i + 1), cities[i], "")`. Check my updated answer. Just copy it and replace your code

Comment: It wants me to change the first param of the method to an int because of i + 1